# About the power spectral density of poly-cyclostationary process

Tags: autocorrelation, stationarity, statistical-power

For a cyclostationary process (CS), I know that the time-averaged power spectral density (PSD) is derived by the Fourier transform of the zeroth-order cyclic autocorrelation function. How about poly-cyclostationary processes (PCS)? Assuming that a PCS composes *N* independent CS and each CS has an incommensurate period *Tn*, does anyone know how to derive the PSD of the PCS?

Comment: Are the $N$ cyclostationary processes _independent_ processes?

Comment: Yes, the cyclostationary processes are independent of each other. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for a very special case only.

Consider the zero-mean cyclostationary processes
$$\{X(t) =\cos(t+\Theta) \colon -\infty < t < \infty\}~\text{and}~\{Y(t) = \cos(\pi t+\Psi) \colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$$
where $\Theta$ and $\Psi$ are *independent* random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi)$. Their autocorrelation functions are $R_X(\tau) = \frac 12\cos(\tau)$ and $R_Y(\tau) = \frac 12\cos(\pi\tau)$ respectively. Furthermore, since functions of independent random variables are independent, these random processes are independent. In particular, $E[X(t_1)Y(t_2)]=E[X(t_1)]E[Y(t_2)]=0$ for all choices of $t_1$ and $t_2$.

If $Z(t) = X(t)+Y(t)$ for all $t$, then it is obvious that $E[Z(t)]=0$. Furthermore,
\begin{align}
E[Z(t)Z(t+\tau)] &= E[(X(t)+Y(t))(X(t+\tau)+Y(t+\tau))]\\
&= E[X(t)X(t+\tau)]+ E[X(t)Y(t+\tau)] + E[Y(t)X(t+\tau)] + E[Y(t)Y(t+\tau)]\\
&= R_X(\tau) + 0 + 0 + R_Y(\tau)\\
&= R_X(\tau) + R_Y(\tau)
\end{align}
Thus, $\{Z(t) = X(t)+Y(t) \colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ is a wide-sense-stationary process and its power spectral density $S_Z(\omega)$ is the sum of the power spectral densities $S_X(\omega)$ and $S_Y(\omega)$ of $\{X(t)\}$ and $\{Y(t)\}$ respectively. Note that $S_X(\omega)$ and $S_Y(\omega)$ consist of two Dirac deltas (at $\pm 1$ and $\pm \pi$) respectively and thus $S_Z(\omega)$ is not a Fourier series as is the case for cyclostationary processes. But hey, if you want _poly_cyclostationarity, you gotta pay a price: after all, TANSTAAFL!

Comment: Thank you Dilip for your answer! The example is very interesting! It seems that generally there doesn't exist a cyclic autocorrelation function to calculate the PSD of a poly-cyclostationary process. I would like to know a bit more about basic properties of (poly-)cyclostationary process. Could you recommend some papers or books?

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Please use your Moderator powers to move your comment to be below the Question so that OP eric will be notified and perhaps even read it. I can't upvote my own answer, and since I am not the OP, I can't accept it either.